# Remove FCM notification

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm, react-native-fcm

I use FCM in my client-server application, and I need to remove the sent notification from the device if it is no longer relevant, for example, if a person has read it already, it needs to be done from the server, I can do it, I tried to use tag but I don't find such information, other applications can do it(((, another problem is to delete notifications on the device when a person opened the letter but the notification remains, the module has a `void RemoveNotification (int id)`, but what is a notification id, where can I get it int and this cannot be a tag or collapse key, I tried to transfer notification, but unsuccessfully
pls help me solve the problem

Comment: Can you please post some actual code?

Answer (score 0):

As FCM tutorial for Android notification, I think you must send another FCM message to your device, with instruction of which notifications to removed. Then handle remove of them in your `FirebaseMessagingService` which was kept ids of notifications shown somewhere or query on currently visible notifications.